# Is there any difference between giving GL15.glBufferData() a float array or a FloatBuffer in LWJGL 3.0?

Tags: java, opengl, buffer, lwjgl, floatbuffer

I was recently watching a tutorial on writing an OpenGL game in Java with LWJGL. In it, the narrator/author first converts the float array from `float[]` to a `FloatBuffer` before giving it to`GL15.glBufferData()`. Initially I didn't think much of this, but I accidentally gave `GL15.glBufferData()` the float array directly instead of converting it to a `FloatBuffer`, and the code ended up working anyway. I [looked up the documentation](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL15.html#glBufferData(int,float%5B%5D,int)) and it only says "Array version of: BufferData" as comment, which still leaves me uncertain.

This leads me to wonder, is there any point of going through the effort to convert `float[]` to a `FloatBuffer` when calling `GL15.glBufferData()` in LWJGL 3.0 with Java 15, assuming the `FloatBuffer` was given its value by using `FloatBuffer::put()` and thus contains the same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between a *direct* NIO Buffer and a float array is that when you hand a float array to LWJGL, it will first need to pin the array using a JNI call into the Java runtime, which will give LWJGL's native code a virtual memory address it can hand over to the actual called native function. Then, the float array needs to be unpinned again, making it eligible again for garbage collection.

With a *direct* NIO Buffer, this does not need to happen, because *direct* NIO Buffers are already backed by a native virtual memory address. So using *direct* NIO Buffers is considerably faster (performance-wise). Of course, all this performance is somewhat lost when you first create a float array and then copy it into the NIO Buffer.

You are expected to simply *not* use a float array to being with, but only ever populate your *direct* NIO Buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a float[] instead of a FloatBuffer because a float[] seems to work more, and it's exactly what you expect: an array of bytes on the stack. Also, behind the scenes, a FloatBuffer is really just a float[] so it doesnt matter TOO much at the end of the day. To continue off my point, converting a float[] to a FloatBuffer seems unnecessary and overly complicated.