# What's the recommended way to populate a Buffer with a predetermined set of data for use with LWJGL 3.0?

Tags: java, opengl, buffer, lwjgl, nio

Following up the accepted answer on [Is there any difference between giving GL15.glBufferData() a float array or a FloatBuffer in LWJGL 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66752349), I understand that ideally you should use a `Buffer` instead of an array of primitives when using `GL15.glBufferData()` for optimal performance. However, [looking at an example on the LWJGL wiki](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/The_Quad_with_DrawArrays.html#Setting_up_the_quad_VBO_and_VAO), it looks like they just use primitives that then are used to create a `Buffer`, which according to the aforementioned answer would negate the performance benefits of using a `Buffer` in the first place.

Which leads me to the question: If I have a static set of data (like the vertices in the linked example), what's the optimal way to populate my `Buffer` with this data? Should I just create a buffer with `BufferUtils` and then use `put()` to populate it with my primitive array, or is there a better way that allows me to avoid the primitive array altogether? In my case I have floats, but I presume it'll be the same regardless of data type.

Comment: wiki site seems to be down

Comment: @MudkipHacker Must've been temporary. It loaded for me when I wrote this and it loaded for me just now.